# ApplicationContext not getting loaded from classpath

Tags: java, spring

I have been pulling my hair out for more than a hour trying to get this to work.

The problem is when I run my application in STS the app runs great, now after I packaged it gives me the following error-

```
WARN  [2014-08-16 12:42:08,620]             org.springframework.core.io.support.PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver: Cannot search for matching files underneath class path resource [META-INF/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
! java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [META-INF/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: rsrc:META-INF/
```

I have moved the context around and tried everything other posts said yet no avail.

Current classpath is `"classpath:/META-INF/*.xml"` and the file is located in `resources/META_INF/applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Are you running a web application or a stand alone one? In web application you should have the META-INF directory at same level of WEB-INF

Comment: Its a dropwizard application, so no WEB-INF

Comment: Path not found exception is pulling hair.

Comment: well then check if really the directory is created in the application; I don't know dropwizard application, but I guess it's a jar, so check if, in the jar, the META-INF directory is present. Moreover, I guess you should specify the classpath to the application